# Getting idea for using Call statement

Tags: cobol

I need to ask what is the problem in this my menu program,when i call another program

by tapping 1 or 2, and when the program called i could not go back to my menu program,

can you help me please how can i get back to my menu when i press Esc key,or does

my Call statment is wrong.

this is the code for my menu program.

```
LINKAGE SECTION.
   01 MY-PROG1 PIC X.
   01 MY-PROG2 PIC X.

......
......
......

MAIN.

       DISPLAY MENU-HEADER ERROR-MESSAGE.
       PERFORM ENTRY-MENU UNTIL CHOICE = 3.     
       STOP RUN.

   ENTRY-MENU.
       ACCEPT MENU-SELECT.
       PERFORM INPUT-CHOICE UNTIL CHOICE = 3.
       STOP RUN.

   INPUT-CHOICE.
       IF CHOICE = 1
         CALL  'MY-PROGRAM1' USING MY-PROG1 
       ELSE IF CHOICE =2
         CALL 'MY-PROGRAM2' USING MY-PROG2
       ELSE 
          MOVE "INVALID INPUT....." TO ERRMSG
          DISPLAY ERROR-MESSAGE.
```

this is MY-PROGRAM1.COB this is how i call back the menu program when i press Esc key

```
LINKAGE SECTION.
   01   MY-PROG1 PIC X.
   01   MY-MENU  PIC X.

......
......
......


MAIN.

 .......
 .......
 STOP RUN.

ENTER-BIRTHDATE.

  ACCEPT...
  .......

  IF ESC-KEY
     DISPLAY CLEAR-SCREEN
     CALL 'MENU'

  ELSE IF F10
    .....
    .....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should replace the `STOP RUN` statement in the called programm with `GOBACK`.

This is the general rules of using `STOP RUN` and `GOBACK`:

> The GOBACK statement marks the logical end of a called program.
>
> General Rules
>   If a GOBACK statement is executed in a program which is under the control of a calling runtime element, the object program operates as if executing an EXIT PROGRAM statement that has the same clauses as the GOBACK statement. See the topic The EXIT Statement.
>   If a GOBACK statement without the ADDRESS OF clause is executed in a program which is not under the control of a calling runtime element, the object program operates as if executing a STOP RUN statement that has the same clauses as the GOBACK statement.
>   If a GOBACK statement with the ADDRESS OF clause is executed in a program which is not under the control of a calling runtime element, the object program operates as if executing a STOP RUN statement except that an arbitrary returned value is set in the system area. The GOBACK statement may result in more compact code than the equivalent EXIT PROGRAM and STOP RUN statement.
>   A GOBACK statement must not be executed while executing a declarative procedure in which the GLOBAL phrase is specified except in a program called while executing that declarative procedure.
>   If a GOBACK statement is executed in a function, the function operates as if executing an EXIT FUNCTION statement.
>   If a GOBACK statement is executed in a method, the method operates as if executing an EXIT METHOD statement.
>   If a GOBACK statement is executed in an iterator, the iterator operates as if executing an EXIT ITERATOR statement.
>
> STOP RUN. This depends on your system.
>   STOP RUN on most compilers terminates the program and if it is called by another cobol program then the whole process is terminated.

At the end of this [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v3r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.cics.ts31.doc/dfhp3/dfhp3p9.htm) you can find a nice schema that represent all those relations.

Edit : (from an old Microsoft Cobol documentation)

> EXIT PROGRAM STATEMENT :
>   The EXIT PROGRAM statement, appearing in a called
>   subprogram, causes control to be returned to the
>   next executable statement after CALL in the calling
>   program.
>   This statement must be a paragraph by
>   itself.

Comment: hi alain.janinm,thank you for the quick reply and for the discussion that helps me enlighten my mind.thank you so much

Comment: by the way does the GOBACK STATEMENT works for the MS COBOl 2.20?

Comment: Actually I've never used MS Cobol, I've worked with Microfocus Cobol. I've tried to find some documentation but unsuccessfully, it seems it's quite old... So I guess you can use GOBACK, try and let me know!

Comment: yup it's true it's never used today. i am also looking for the documentation still no luck.Okay i will let you know if this works.thank you again.

Comment: @jemz I made an edit with an other possible statement you can use. I've found a Microsoft Cobol documentation, not sure it apply for your version but it's the only Microsoft and Cobol doc I found : http://bitsavers.org/pdf/microsoft/cpm/Microsoft_COBOL-80_1978.pdf

Comment: ,I've tried to use the GOBACK but it's not working.it says "unrecognizable element is ignored: GOBACK"

Comment: Okay i will try to read this PDF file,maybe i can find useful on this.thank you again.

Comment: @jemz yeah try the EXIT PROGRAM statement, I put the description in my answer.

Comment: i tried the EXIT statement at first when i tapped the no.1 it calls my program1 and then i Tapped the Esc key and it goes back to Menu Program and i Tapped again no.1 it execute back again the program1 but i tapped the Esc key it generates run time error "Insufficient memory for program,Program: program1 etc..how can i fixed this.?

Comment: You wrote `PERFORM INPUT-CHOICE UNTIL CHOICE = 3.` but choice value is never set to 3 no?

Comment: An when you press escape you shouldn't call 'menu' again and again but exit the programm to return in menu I guess.